# Moq throw exception for any member

Tags: moq

Is there a way to configure a mock to throw an exception for any member of the interface being mocked?

I'm aware of:

```
_mockDependancy.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).Throws<Exception>();
```

which configures the .DoSomething() method to throw, however I'm looking for something like:

```
_mockDependancy.SetReturnsDefault<int>(-1);
```

which saves me having to specify the exact method.  So, ideally something like:

```
_mockDependancy.SetThrowsDefault<Exception>();
```

Comment: Looking [at the source](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/756bf4e3e7b213c6d819ae7acd5e04280a07a040/Source/Mock.cs#L1040), I don't see any support for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contributor for the Moq project pointed out to me that this can be achieved by creating the Mock with MockBehavior.Strict

```
_mockDependancy= new Mock<IDependancy>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

then, any member that has not been .Setup() will throw:

```
MockException()
```